# Wowslider works but doesn't display the pics

Tags: jquery, css, wowslider

I am a very new user and have limited knowledge. But I am trying to figure  it out myself and move forward. I am using Wowslider on my website to display images. The slider(carousel) works just good but isn't displaying any photos.The path to the photos are correct. The link to the page is - www.trumpetevents.in (under the portforlio tab from the menu on the left site of the page).
What could go wrong and any quick fixes?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Open your browser's console and view the errors and you'll see where the issue is

Answer (score 1):

Path to your image is uncorrect check it again

[image: Path to your image is uncorrect check it again]

Answer (score 0):

Your image path is wrong.use background-image like this:

```
    {
        background-image: url(admin/images/22.jpg);
    }
```

instead of:

```
    {
        background-image: url(admin/images/portfolio_image/22.jpg);
    }
```